Integral with respect to a countable sum of measures equals the sum of the integrals with respect to the single measures
Given this question, i was wondering if the simpler problem:

If $a_n\gt 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist measures $m_n$ such that
$m=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n m_n$ and $f$ is a non-negative measurable function integrable with respect to $m$ and each $m_n$ then $$\int f\,dm=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n \int f\,dm_n$$

could be proved straightforward from the definition of the integral using the fact that the result holds for simple function and that for sets of non-negative numbers we have that $sup\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty x:x\in E_i\}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ sup\{x:x\in E_i\}$, like this
Proof:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int f dm &= \sup\Big\{ \int \Phi dm: \ 0\leq\Phi\leq f, \Phi \textrm{ is a simple}  \Big\}\\
&=\sup\Big\{ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int \Phi dm_n: \ 0\leq\Phi\leq f, \Phi \textrm{ is a simple}  \Big\}\\
&= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup\Big\{ \int \Phi dm_n: \ 0\leq\Phi\leq f, \Phi \textrm{ is a simple}  \Big\}\\
&= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int f dm_n
\end{aligned}
$$
In particular, i'm not sure if, in this particular case, is legit to interchange infinite sum and supremum and conclude with the last equality.

Hi, welcome to this site. You tagged solution verification for this question. For this type of question, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
